# Adding Dynamic Markers to gmaps4rails rendering

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript, gmaps4rails

At present, the implementation of gmaps4railsy allows for the placed markers to be one style:

[image]

But I want to allow for dynamic markers so that a number could appear in a marker that would represent a locations id or store number as from the database row it's pulling the lat/long information from as (crudely):

[image]

How can this be implemented in gmaps4ails?

Comment: gmaps4rails is just a google maps wrapper, do you know  solution with google maps?

Comment: @apneadiving No, I am not aware of the solution with Google maps

Comment: ok an easy trick is to use this: `http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chst=d_map_pin_letter&chld=123|FE6256|000000` as a picture url. Replace `123` with the number you want